# How to access nested class from instance of a class?

Tags: c#, .net, nested

```
partial class Employee
{
    protected string empName;

    protected int empID = new int();

    protected float currPay;

    protected static int empAge;

    protected string empSNN;

   // these are nested classes

    public class BenefitPackage
    {
        // I want to access this class

        public enum BenefitPackageLevel
        {
            standard,Gold,Platinum
        }
        public double ComputePayDeduction()
        {
            return 125.0;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to access the **BenefitPackageLevel** class through an instance of employees class like:

```
Employee emp= new Employee() 
var benefitpackage= emp.BenefitPackage.BenefitPackageLevel.standard;
```

but why while I didn't define **BenefitPackage** as a static member, I just can access it through the class level like:

```
Employee.BenefitPackage.BenefitPackageLevel.standard
```

Is it possible that nested classes are static by default?

Answer (score 4):

You are not accessing it as an static member. You are accessing `standard` through its outer types. When you declare a nested type its scope is limited to the outer type so you must access it through its outer type.

For example if you want to create an instance of `BenefitPackage` you should do it like this:

```
var benefitPackage = new Employee.BenefitPackage();
```

So when you want to access `standard` as a value of `BenefitPackageLevel` enumeration you must use it like this:

```
var temp = Employee.BenefitPackage.BenefitPackageLevel.standard;
```

Nested types are inaccessible to external types unless you made them public.

Keep in mind that when you create an instance of an outer type it does not create an instance of its inner types.

Comment: but how you access inner enum BenefitPackageLevel type?

Comment: @Mohsen Read the answer again? dotctor showed you how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of issues with your code. First you need to do this change to your `BenefitPackage` class:

```
public class BenefitPackage
{
   // Your code...

   public BenefitPackageLevel Level { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to do make this change to your `Employee` class and add the following property:

```
partial class Employee
{
   // Your code...

   public Employee()
   {
      this.EmoloyeeBenefitPackage = new BenefitPackage();
   }
   public BenefitPackage EmployeeBenefitPackage { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
var employee = new Employee();
employee.EmoloyeeBenefitPackage.Level = BenefitPackageLevel.Gold;
var level = employee.EmployeeBenefitPackage.Level;
```

Comment: the second section of your code has a problem. I tried it, it says its ambiguous reference

Comment: which second section and what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @CodingYoshi You cannot have a nested class named `BenefitPackage` and a property with the same name in a single class. The nested type is still a *member* of the parent type, so you cannot have another member (a property) have the same name.

Comment: @poke thank you. I am in my mobile phone so didn't compile it. Good catch.

Comment: Life saver! @CodingYoshi

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused. Because a type is defined within another type, it doesn't mean the outside type contains any instance information unless a field is explicitly defined.

For Example:

```
public class OutsideClass
{
    // Define field or properties to store nested types
    public Select Pick { get; set; }   
    public NestedClass Link { get; set; }
    // Type definitions
    public class NestedClass
    {
    }
    public enum Select
    {
        None,
        One,
        Many,
        All
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OutsideClass a = new OutsideClass();
        a.Pick=OutsideClass.Select.Many;
        a.Link=new OutsideClass.NestedClass();
    }
}
```